# get content of $this->getChildHtml('left')

Tags: magento

I have installed **sns nova theme** for my site.
I need to know from where `$this->getChildHtml('left')` getting data. Inside same there is promotion slider. I need to reposition it to the bottom. Can anybody help me out to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to look on local.xml of your theme if it is correcly packaged, on the layout folder. Else search for left on the same folder to see where is the xml declaration. Once you found, you can check which blocks are called and the according template. I believe that your left child consist of many templates but I cannot be sure as I do not know the theme.

Comment: in 2columns-left.phtml file , i got following code snippet: <div id="sns_left" class="span3" data-tablet="span4" data-stablet="span4">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                    </div> if i remove this code left navigation bar goes off . As your suggestion i checked local.xml file. In that file i found <reference name="left">
      <block type="core/template" template="sns/blocks/bannerslide.phtml" after="-" />
        </reference> now if i remove above my left promotion sliding banner hides. But i just want it to display at the bottom of sidebar.

Comment: can you just help me out to solve this.
url is http://aimaxprovider.in/bishtprice/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=desktop+switch
see in side bar promotion banner.